# what can i do if the User-defined signal is not enough

Tags: linux, unix, signals, posix

Linux just have two user-defined signal, SIGUSER1 and SIGUSER2, but they have been used in squid.

I want to use another user-defined signal to invoke my own handler function in squid, what can I do if I want another user-defined signal. I don't want socket as the way to communicate between processes.

Anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 4):

I am not at all sure that avoiding pipes (or `AF_UNIX` sockets, or named pipes) is sensible in your case (inside the `squid` proxy).

As [Duck answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963966/841108) you could consider using POSIX real-time signals.

But signal processing is tricky (and brittle, and hard to get right, and hard to reliably test). Read very carefully and several times [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and consider also the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)...

<sup>Notice that the *restriction* to use only *async-signal-safe functions* -directly or indirectly- inside signal handlers is a very *strong* one. You can't even call (even indirectly) `malloc` (or `operator new` in C++ which is often used in many standard C++ containers) or `fprintf` inside a signal handler. You could consider setting some `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag in it.</sup>

You could use the Linux specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) or [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html); you could also use the Posix standard [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) which is quite efficient on Linux (even if you [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) one byte at each time).

<sup>Notice that you can emulate `signalfd` outside of Linux on other Posix systems by `write`-ing one byte into a `pipe` f.d. from inside the signal handler. This is permitted (and suggested by Qt documentation).</sup>

You speak of extending the [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy (perhaps [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol) could be relevant). And `squid` has obviously a very reliable [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (perhaps using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or some other multiplexing), so this suggests on the contrary to use something file descriptor based like pipes, `eventfd`, `signalfd`, sockets (e.g. `AF_UNIX` ones, see [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), or named pipes with [mkfifo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html), etc....).

And file descriptors can be made signaling (with `SIGIO` signal and [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) `F_SETOWN` and `F_SETFL`).

Actually, within Squid, I would believe that using signals is wrong.

<sup>AFAIK, Linux deals much better and much faster with file descriptors than with signals.</sup>

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [POSIX real-time signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).  From the linked man page:

> Unlike standard signals, real-time signals have no predefined meanings: the entire set of real-time signals can be used for application-defined purposes.

It would be advisable to read about and understand them first.